# How to validate fields with if conditional in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am validating a json file, I need to validate in a field that if it is null, assign a default value, I can't find how to perform a validation with if conditional

```
file.json
```

```
{  
    "timeout": 100
}
```

```
jq -r .timeout fiile.json
```

here it prints the value correctly, I need to validate if this field is null to assign it a default value with jq

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify what if anything should be done if the "timeout" field (key) is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [update operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment%3A%7C%3D) `|=` to update the field in question. For the conditional just compare to `null`.

```bash
jq '.timeout |= if . == null then 200 else . end'
```

If your input file is

```json
{  
  "timeout": 100
}
```

it will stay the same, as `.timeout` is not `null`. But if it is

```json
{  
  "timeout": null
}
```

then it will be changed to the default value given, here:

```json
{  
  "timeout": 200
}
```

Note that this only triggers for the content of `null`. There are other means to test for `false`, the number zero `0`, the empty string `""`, etc., even the complete absence of that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternative operator `//`

```
jq '.timeout //= 200' file.json
```